# Not able to import pandas and numpy

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to run following simple script on Debian Stable Linux:

```
$ cat ./mytest.py 
#! /usr/bin/python3

print("Before importing sys.")
import sys

print("Before importing pandas.")
import pandas as pd

print("Before importing numpy.")
import numpy as np
```

But it is giving following error:

```
$ ./mytest.py 
Before importing sys.
Before importing pandas.
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=22, tm_min=43, tm_sec=50, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=326, tm_isdst=0)
Date=22
Month=11
Year=2017
Hour=22
Minute=43
Second=50
Local current time : Wed Nov 22 22:43:50 2017
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mytest.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/home/iuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/iuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/iuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/iuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/iuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception
```

Following versions of pandas and numpy are installed through Debian Repositories:

```
Package                 Installed       Previous        Now             State
=======================-===============-===============-===============-=====
python3-pandas          0.19.2-5.1      0.19.2-5.1      0.19.2-5.1      install
python3-pandas-lib      0.19.2-5.1      0.19.2-5.1      0.19.2-5.1      install

python-numpy            1:1.12.1-3      1:1.12.1-3      1:1.12.1-3      install
python3-numpy           1:1.12.1-3      1:1.12.1-3      1:1.12.1-3      install
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

---

Edit: I find that the same above file works perfectly in another folder! I am using correct filename for command.

```
$ ./mytest.py 
Before importing sys.
Before importing pandas.
Before importing numpy.
```

There are other files and sub-folders in first folder. One of which is `__pycache__` which contains following files:

```
$ ls
datetime.cpython-35.pyc  myfns.cpython-35.pyc  myframe.cpython-35.pyc
```

My datetime.py file has following:

```
import time

tt = time.localtime()
print(tt)
print("Date="+str(tt.tm_mday))
print("Month="+str(tt.tm_mon))
print("Year="+str(tt.tm_year))
print("Hour="+str(tt.tm_hour))
print("Minute="+str(tt.tm_min))
print("Second="+str(tt.tm_sec))

localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime() )   # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< same as complex above; 
print ("Local current time :", localtime)
```

Is it possible these are interfering?

Comment: Maybe numpy is installed in python2 and is being used in python3. Try reinstalling it

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Pandas is using Numpy internally (heavily)

Comment: Pandas does use numpy so that might have been the issue.

Comment: Please see edit in my question above.

Comment: Yes `__pycache__` I have seen it ruining imports so many time. Will the import work if you delete the cache?

Comment: When I delete `__pycache__` and re-run mytest.py, the error remains and I find that the folder `__pycache__` has been created again with a file named `datetime.cpython-35.pyc`.

Comment: I deleted `__pycache__` folder and also datetime.py from this folder. Now the script works perfectly. What is the reason?

Comment: I renamed datetime.py to mydatetime.py and now it does not interfere. Probably there is a file named datetime.py in numpy/pandas and file in current folder was being picked up. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script was working well in other folders, the problem was in this folder only. There was a file named `datetime.py` in this folder, removal of which resolved the problem. Apparently, `pandas` looks for a file named `datetime.py` and searches first the current folder, where it finds this user file with same name. Hence the problem.

Moral of the story: User files should not be given general names that may be being used by software packages.

Comment: Thank you! I just randomly had this same issue. I deleted the datetime.py that I created and now I can stop pulling out my hair. Thank you so very much.

Comment: Same filename! Very interesting! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that `Pandas 0.19.2` is compatible with `Numpy 1.12.1`.

I think the easiest way to approach this problem is to [install Anaconda Python distributive into a separate directory (not touching system Python)](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) and create VirtualEnv(s).

Anaconda takes care of compatibility of all provided modules.

Comment: Yeah I personally do prefer conda. Maybe its the best in the market I guess

Comment: @Bharath, same here! I love Anaconda distributive! It makes everything so much simpler.

Comment: Sir I dont know why when I install packages with pip it never works for jupyter, I have to install few more times. Conda somehow makes it so universal to access. I too love it.